# C# problem with dot in resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resource-file

I'm having a little problem with a dot (`.`) in a resource file. In my `global.resx` file I have the value:

```
Key: DSNLBuiltNo
Value: DS.NLM + Built no
```

When I display this in my Razor file with a `@Html.Label(Global.DSNLBuiltNo)` I only see `NLM + Built no` in my page (and the underlying HTML.) Anyone knows what is going on here?

Comment: Please show actual sample code.

Comment: Create asp.net mvc 3 project
Add resource file called Global

Add resource key and value and create a page with in it
@Html.Label(Global.DSNLBuiltNo)

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way the `Label` method works. By only including one string you're basically saying that the label is for that particular id. Since you didn't provide the actual label text it assumes that you're referencing an actual property somewhere and only uses the property name itself and not it's fully qualified namespace. To get the output you're expecting (if a `label` is the proper output) then you want to use:

```
@Html.Label(Global.DSNLBuiltNo, Global.DSNLBuiltNo)
```

or if you don't really need a label since it's not referencing an actual id anywhere

```
@Global.DSNLBuiltNo
```